# Can ssh_config's ProxyCommand run a local command before connecting to a remote machine?

Tags: proxy, openssh

Before I can to connect to a particular remote machine I have to run a certain local command. So instead of `ssh me@remote.machine` I have to do

```
local_command
ssh me@remote.machine
```

I would like to automate this so that I only have to do `ssh remote.machine`.

I know that I can achieve this at the shell level by creating my own `ssh` script that calls `/usr/bin/ssh`, but can I do it using the [ProxyCommand](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) option of `ssh_config`?

As far as I understand it, I need something like

```
Host remote.machine
    ProxyCommand local_command; ssh me@remote.machine
```

in my `~/.ssh/config` file, but not exactly this of course because it's circular!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If using `ProxyCommand`, you must use something like `/usr/bin/nc` to connect the server.

For invoking your command before connect, you need to use `sh -c "command list"` to merge the two commands as one.

```
Host remote.machine
    ProxyCommand sh -c "local_command; /usr/bin/nc %h %p"
```

**MORE:**

If your `local_command` is too complicated, you can use a script:

```
cat my_connect.sh
#!/bin/bash

local_command
/usr/bin/nc "$1" "$2"
```

The ssh config becomes:

```
Host remote.machine
        ProxyCommand /path_to_my_connect.sh %h %p
```

At the last, you can add your own proxy to the `/usr/bin/nc`

Comment: Is there any way to run this local_command if it's an interactive script? I can't seem to get it working. Any help? Posted here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1117873/ssh-config-how-to-automatically-execute-an-interactive-script-locally-before-co

Answer (score 1):

Use the example from the page you linked:

`ProxyCommand /usr/bin/nc -X connect -x 192.0.2.1:8080 %h %p`

Invokes nc (netcat) to connect to a proxy (proxy running on 192.0.2.1:8080) and passes %h and %p to the ssh command (%h = hostname, %p = port)