# .ssh/config to start remote session in zsh

Tags: ssh, zsh, remote, session

I would like to start a remote session without typing the following command

```
ssh user@remoteserverip -t zsh
```

I know that I can change the host names in the `~/.ssh/config` to simply use something like this:

```
ssh serveralias -t zsh
```

But I want to remove the `-t zsh` parameter.

Is there a way to achieve this without writing a function?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44307/can-ssh-configs-proxycommand-run-a-local-command-before-connecting-to-a-remote

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that is possible with `~/.ssh/config`. The `-t` can be covered by adding a `RequestTTY yes`, but it doesn't seem you can specify the remote command in `~/.ssh/config`.

However, with `zsh`, you could add a:

```
alias -g 'serveralias=serveralias -t zsh'
```

to your `~/.zshrc`.

Or make a function like:

```
zssh() ssh "$@" -t zsh
```

Comment: Is that `alias` really correct? Check your quotes.

Comment: I think I'll go with this solution thanks!

Answer (score 16):

For anyone arriving here years later, since 2017 it's possible to put everything in the config file:

```
Host host_1
    HostName 1.2.3.4
    User root
    Port 22
    RequestTTY yes
    RemoteCommand zsh
```

Comment: Best answer as of 2019. This answer needs more upvotes!

Answer (score 5):

I concur with @Stephane that there isn't a way to do this using the `~/.ssh/config file`. Another approach would be to use the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the remote server. If you add a line like this:

```
command="exec zsh" ssh-dss ..... rest of key ....
```

Then you can just ssh as normal and you'll get a zsh on the remote server.

#### Example

On server, ssh to remote.

```
$ ssh saml@greeneggs
```

On remote server, confirming we're in a `zsh`.

```
[saml@greeneggs]~% ps -eaf|grep $$
saml      1974  1973  1 10:34 pts/3    00:00:00 zsh
saml      2023  1974  0 10:34 pts/3    00:00:00 ps -eaf
saml      2024  1974  0 10:34 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 1974
```

You can do more elaborate things using this file, see this Q&A, titled: [ssh, start a specific shell, and run a command on the remote machine?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20729/ssh-start-a-specific-shell-and-run-a-command-on-the-remote-machine).

Comment: `command="exec zsh"` is a bad idea: it makes it impossible to run ssh with an explicit command (so goodbye scp, rsync, …). http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20739 shows how to do this decently.

Comment: I wasn't aware that it is possible to use the authorized_keys to execute commands. it is a pretty nice idea, but I'll use the solution from stephane because the issue pointed by Gilles.

Thanks

Comment: @Gilles - yeah I found your solution and just showed the potential here, didn't want to just copy your solution here, that's why I referenced yours at the bottom of mine answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo usermod -s /bin/zsh yourusername
```

Answer (score 0):

You better change the system shell setting.

1. Connect to server normally. `ssh serveralias`
2. Execute `chsh` to change system shell
3. Enter `/bin/zsh` to set it to zsh
4. Reconnect with `ssh serveralias` and it'll show `%`

`chsh [username]` can be used to change other user's setting without reconnection.