# SSH config file - Run command before connection

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-config

i cannot run a command before connect with ssh to remote server using ~/.ssh/config file.

I have tried with options "ProxyCommand" and "LocalCommand" but it doesn't work.

- ProxyCommand: seems it run the command, but after that doesn't ask me the password of ssh connection
- LocalCommand: run the command only if the connection successful

Comment: Have you considered aliases or functions?

Comment: Theorectically it could be done with ProxyCommand and passing a scriptname that contains what you want to be executed, but you need to ensure that the script ends with setting up a connection to the remote host, fulfilling the "proxy" part. E.g. `/usr/bin/nc %h %p`

Comment: What command in particular are you trying to run?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks for your answare. Yes, before i was using aliases, but config file of ssh is more portable and smart than aliases.

Comment: @wurtel Thanks for your answare. Can i put my command and on success execute "nc" without log?

E.g. ```/bin/echo hello > /tmp/test && /usr/bin/nc %h %p > /dev/null 2>&1```

Comment: @DamianT. Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to execute a custom script

Comment: Don't redirect the `nc` output, `ssh` needs that to communicate with the remote host!

Comment: @wurtel i have tried with this syntax
``` ProxyCommand /usr/local/bin/script && /usr/bin/nc 192.x.x.x 22 ```
but it doesnt ask me the password for the ssh connection and it seems stay pending... Any suggest?

Comment: Add the `nc` command to your script, I wouldn't be surprised if ProxyCommand may only be a simple command and not a shell command line.

Comment: Hi @wurtel i can't edit the script... Any suggestion?

Comment: I have found the solution! ```ProxyCommand bash -c "/usr/local/bin/script && /usr/bin/nc 192.x.x.x 22"```
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See these answers: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44343 (using ProxyCommand) and https://askubuntu.com/a/1268036 (using Match host ... exec)

Comment: I solved with the Match host! Thank you @silas-s-brown :)